# Ruby console parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby script we can pass parameter like this in console:

```
 `ruby r3.rb sam sou "samarth pandey"`
```

this will receive in a array but now i want to send parameter like this

```
 `ruby sam sou {:sam => abc, :sou => abc}`
```

So how can i do this i don't want to make my hash as string like

```
 `ruby sam sou "{:sam => abc, :sou => abc}"`
```

Comment: why not stringify your hash, and evaluate it?  Seems like a perfectly reasonable way to go about it, if you're not going to just put the values in some init file.

Comment: Check this class http://apidock.com/ruby/OptionParser. There's comprehensive example of handling command line parameters/options/switches.

Comment: its a good way i am aware about that as i mention in my question but now i am looking for some other solution as this i have to do on cloud config file so its not advisable to do lots of operation over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to pass the hash without quotes, because the shell would recognize `>` as an output redirection and pipe the output of your script into a file called `abc}`.

EDITED:

With the Ruby 1.9 Hash syntax you could do something like this:

foo.rb:

```
p eval(ARGV.join(' ').gsub(/: (.+?)([,|}])/, ': "\1"\2'))
```

In the shell:

```
$ ruby foo.rb {lkj: dssd, kjdsh: kldiu} #=> {:lkj=>"dssd", :kjdsh=>"kldiu"}
```

I think this is not very elegant nor is the syntax valid Ruby since the quotes of the values are missing, but it would be a solution for your task.